# What is current approach to Laravel and Stripe Checkout for Single Payments?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe Checkout on my Laravel 5.3 website for some fairly basic purchase fulfillment.

I have been reading a lot lately about Laravel and Stripe Checkout for single purchases. For instance this:

https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe/episodes/1

As well as

https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/stripe-payments-in-laravel-the-ultimate-guide/

In both examples from the links above, it is assumed that Stripe will not perform the purchase, but instead will send a token back to your site for you to then complete the purchase on your backend.

On the stripe site where it goes over Stripe Connect - https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time - I don't see any indication that Stripe payment should not be handled directly on the Stripe server.

I am thinking that maybe previous loopholes made developers feel that payment had to be on backend, but in current Stripe docs I don't see any warnings to that effect and seems that Stripe Checkout is indeed meant to handle payment, and then for you to do post payment actions on your site.

So, just curious if there is a current body of Laravel knowledge on this topic, as the links I provided above may be a bit out of date.

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: The Laravel guide is referencing older version of Checkout. The one you linked later is the newer version (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time). The newer version handles tokenization + payments for you. It allows for front-end only or frontend+backend integration. The old Checkout created tokens client-side only. You had to send the token to your backend and create a charge manually. I'd recommend looking into the newer version of Checkout, it could suit your use-case.

Comment: Ok, will give it a try! Now just have to determine under which use cases client side vs server side makes sense for Checkout.

Comment: So far test is working fine but has me wondering if users prefer to see the same domain when going to purchase or if the general public is used to payment gateway pages that take them away from the original domain. Since stripe provides ability to go to success url I guess that gets user back to original domain but just wonder what is considered best approach from trust standpoint.